# How do I repaint a particular cell in PyQt5

Tags: python, oop, pyqt5, qpainter, conways-game-of-life

I'm attempting to create Conway's Game of Life in Pyqt5 and am unsure how to update my grid to change the color of a particular cell. 
My program has a GUI class, board class, and a class for the Lifeform. This method is in the class with the lifeforms. Should I create another paintevent outside of my GUI class? Do I make some object for the GUI that I should reference instead (this approach doesn't make sense when I say it to myself because making an object for the GUI referenced outside the GUI seems like bad design but idk) I posted my method below because I feel my question may not be complicated and I'm just missing something.

```
def paintWhite(self): #LifeForm Class

   screensize = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
    cellwidth = screensize.width()//GLOBAL_N #GlobalN x GlobalN grid
    cellheight = screensize.height()//GLOBAL_N
    paintObject = QPainter()
    paintObject.setPen(QPen(Qt.white, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
    paintObject.setBrush(QColor(255,255,255))
    paintObject.drawRect(cellwidth * self.row, cellheight * self.col, cellwidth,cellheight)

#Seperate Code Snippets

def paintEvent(self,e): #Gui Class
    paintObject = QPainter(self)
    paintObject.setPen(QPen(Qt.black, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
    paintObject.setBrush(QColor(0,0,0))
    n=50
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            x = paintObject.drawRect(self.width//n*i, self.height//n*j, self.width//n,self.height//n)
```

There is just no color change. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Repainting is done with the setstylesheet and has been answered here in stackoverflow already -- try searching on setstylesheet

Comment: @DennisJensen No, what you say is incorrect. When setting up a Qt StyleSheet triggers an event that creates an internal QStyle that repaints all widgets that are handled by that QStyle, but that is not the only way to repaint, not every widget needs QSS to be repainted.

Comment: From your code it's very unclear what widget is actually painting and when (also, the first snippet of code doesn't seem to work, both because it doesn't seem to be called inside a paint event and because you've not `begin()` the painter. Anyway, if you need to (re)paint a widget, just call its `update()` method.

Comment: Note did not mean to say Repaint -- meant to just say Paint.  However @eyllanesc your comment implies that my answer is wrong -- which then implies you have the answer but did not post it?  If no then why add in a confusing comment?  Or why not explain a bit further about other ways to paint?  Or at least provide a link to explain your comment.

Comment: @DennisJensen 1) My comment only indicates that what you indicate is incorrect, I indicate that without taking into account the answer, if you use incorrect terms then that brings confusion. 2) If the OP provides an MRE I could provide an adequate response, I do not publish an answer because the answer depends on the context, for example I do not know how much cost the algorithm used to generate the positions of the painted rectangles, etc.

Comment: @DennisJensen  3) Due to point 2 I am prudent and I am waiting for a comment that shows the interest of the OP. 4) does not provide links except for the docs or SO questions/answers, but in this case there is not one that fits. 4) If my comments cause confusion then ask clearly what you do not understand.

Comment: @DennisJensen 5) What  musicamante says is a good start to the answer. 6) The OP asks how to make a repaint that is different from the use of Qt Style Sheets. 7) When I feel I have the necessary information then I will post an answer, if you already have it we invite you to provide it.

Comment: @ellyanesc I did provide a basic answer AND it actually might be THE answer it all depends on what they are trying to do exactly -- pointing them to Style Sheet is an attempt to help the OP answer their own incomplete question by providing them something to dig into that might cover what they might be trying to do -- now had the question been complete to the point that I could derive a solid answer like you I would have posted that answer as an answer -- however I would not have shot down a potential answer with a comment without supplying additional information which you did not do